# Will installing VirtualBox from software center wipe out my VMs?

Tags: virtualbox, software-center, 15.10

I installed VirtualBox via the download from Oracle's website. However, I'd like to get updates through the software center.
I'm concerned that doing so will wipe out my virtual machine. Is this the case, or is it seamless?

I'm exporting an appliance of my VM now (which I assume is a backup), but I'd like to know anyway.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-installing VirtualBox from the software repository should not harm the VM's that you have, although the version of VirtualBox available at Oracle (5.0.10) is substantially newer than the one in the software repository (5.0.4).  I believe the program also checks on occasion for updates, although I have not run VB in quite a while.

Backups: Always a good thing.  Do that more often.  You will find a directory in your home area, probably with a name line `virtualbox`.   Inside this directory, you will find all sorts of subdirectories names like your virtual machines.  These are in fact, your VMs and an adequate backup, is to backup these directories.  Exporting the appliance is nice, but in my experience does not work too well.